# clunky jQuery - Safari behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I cant seem to find any past questions that can clarify this.

I have a very basic jQuery function which alters the margin of a div when the user scrolls. It simply adds and reduces half a pixel for each pixel scrolled by the user, to create a slow moving div response.

Here is my relevant code:

jQuery

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".img-anm-text").css('margin', '-750' - -0.6*fromTop + 'px auto');
  });
```

CSS

```
.img-anm-frm {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.img-anm-text {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20pt;
    margin-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
        z-index: 9;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="img-anm-frm">
<div class="img-anm-text"><h1 style="margin-bottom: -5px;">TITLE</h1>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

The problem I face is a very clunky and jittery movement when loaded in safari. I feel like this is a very simple piece of code, but safari doesnt seem to handle it. Does anyone know something which works smoother? or perhaps a work around?

Comment: Just a side note: In `'-750' - -0.6*fromTop + 'px auto'`, that initial string will be converted to a number, may as well just write it as one from the outset: `-750 - -0.6*fromTop + 'px auto'` Once you've done that, of course, `- -0.6*fromTop` is a kinda long way to write `+ 0.6*fromTop`. So perhaps `(-750 + 0.6*fromTop) + 'px auto'` or even `(0.6*fromTop - 750) + 'px auto'`

Comment: @T.J Crowder Now that you mention it, you're totally right. I just swapped the signs around from a previous function I made similar to that (Which required a little bit more arithmetic). Do you think that could be the result of the clunky safari display?

Comment: Sadly, no, I wouldn't expect it to be. :-)